# jQuery clone() with increment value and input field issues

Tags: jquery

I have 2 main issues with my clone() script.

1. Whenever I clone a div, I'd like to change the text with the increment value. Eg, the new block should have the title "Block 2"... and so on.
2. When I click on the radio button and clone it, the cloned block still has the radio selected. I already have the value set to empty value in the script but it does not seem to be working on the first clone.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="mydiv">
        <div class="title">Block 1</div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="blockoption" value="left"> Radio 1<br />
            <input type="radio" name="blockoption" value="right"> Radio 2<br />
            <select>
                <option selected="selected">Select</option>
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
            </select><br />
            <input type="text" name="blocktext" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input id="addbutton" type="button" value="Add Block" />&nbsp;<input id="removebutton" type="button" value="Remove Block" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("#addbutton").click(function () {
var inc = $('#mydiv').siblings().length;
$('#mydiv:first-child').clone().insertAfter('#mydiv:last-child').find('input').val('');
$('#mydiv').find('.title').each(function() {
    $(this).text().replace(/\d+/, inc+2);
});
});

$("#removebutton").click(function () {
var inc = $('#mydiv').siblings().length;
if (inc > 0) {
    $('#mydiv:last-child').remove('#mydiv');
    $('#mydiv').find('.title').each(function() {
        $(this).text().replace(/\d+/, inc-2);
    });
}
});
```

**See the code in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ms8Ws/1/).**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloning an element that has ID attribute makes your document invalid you can use classes instead. For removing `checked` and `selected` properties you can use `prop` method.

```
$("#addbutton").click(function() {
    var inc = $('.mydiv').length;
    var cloned = $('.mydiv:first').clone()
        .find('.title').text('Block' + ++inc).end()
        .find('input').val('').prop('checked', false).end()
        .find('option').prop('selected', false).end()
        .appendTo('.wrapper')
});

$("#removebutton").click(function() {
    $('.mydiv:last').remove()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b7knT/

Comment: That looks great. You make it look so easy. Thanks so much.

Comment: this method isn't solve the radio button problem, because when i duplicate the group i should change the radio name to. and what if i really need those ID attributes?